# Can a Rails model be associated with the column name of another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling, model-associations

I'm looking for links or documentation about how to solve this rails data modeling issue. It doesn't seem straight forward.

I have a Report model with many columns such as wheel, break, bearing, etc. In each column I'm saving the condition of the part as "good" or "bad". This is the easy part.

However, if any of these columns are "bad" when the report is saved, I'm using an after_save callback to to create a new instance of the Correction model.  In the Correction model I'm saving the report_id as well as the name of the part - wheel, break, etc.

Then I would like to be able to edit the Correction model at the same time as I edit the Report model using accepts_nested_attributes_for. Is this possible? How would I access the specific instance of the Correction model that corresponds to the Report column name? I'm not sure if I would be better off using a different approach for this.

I would be grateful for any links or docs which might help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html accepts_nested_attribute would enable you to create corrections for a given report at the same time that you create the report. But in your case you will create corrections only once the report has been created so i don't think you need to use accepts_nested_attribute.

I think what you would like to do is easy to do and depends how you implemented your Report and Correction model.
Let's suppose your model is similar to this:

```
class Report< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :corrections
  attr_accessible :wheel, :brake, etc...
  after_save :create_corrections_if_bad_parts

  def create_corrections_if_bad_parts
     # For each part if one of them is changed to false, it create a new correction
     self.attributes.keys.each do |key|
       if send(key + "_changed?") and !self.attributes[key]
          # Calling build will fill the report_id for you
          correction = self.corrections.build(broken_part: key)
          correction.save
       end
     end
  end
end

class Correction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  attr_accessible :broken_part
end
```

This model assume you got one column for each parts but if you got too many part it might better to normalize the database or use a hash to store all part....
You can learn more about relationship over there: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks. This is really useful. I have the models set up this way. My method for create_corrections_if_bad_parts is a little different. However, how would I access each correction on the report/edit form?

Comment: I am not sure to understand but you can access to all corrections that belong to the report due to the has many associations.
if you do report.corrections you will have access to an array of collections that are linked to the given report :)

Comment: Thanks again! I knew I could use use report.corrections. I was just trying to show too much in one view, which is why I was getting confused. I've simplified the workflow to make it simpler.